# Segmentation Fault while Calling Lapack function from Eigen

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, eigen, lapack, blas

My program is written in C++ and I use Eigen library for the matrix operations inside it. There is a huge matrix product inside it, and the dimension is 50000*1000 and 1000*50000. So I tried to call the BLAS function from MKL library to improve the performance. Then there is segmentation error while calling the dgemm function.

Here is the code

```
        double alpha = 1, beta = 0;
    double *s1;
    MKL_INT mm1 = q, nn1 = q, kk1 = ncol1;
    s1 = (double *)malloc(q*q*sizeof(double));
    cout << 14 << endl;

    cblas_dgemm(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans,mm1, nn1, kk1, alpha, V.data(), mm1, A01.data(), kk1, beta, s1, mm1);
```

The code works fine with small dimension. I compiles the code with:

```
icpc lapack.cpp generators.cpp SimpleRNG.cpp example.cpp -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lpthread -lm  -DMKL_ILP64 -o new_example.o
```

or

```
icpc lapack.cpp generators.cpp SimpleRNG.cpp example.cpp -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_core -lpthread -lm -o new_example.o
```

i.e: I tried both the LP64 interface and the ILP64 interface, but neither of them work, can anyone help me out here? I run the program on Linux server and there is plenty of memory.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `50000 * 50000 * sizeof(double)` is ~20GB (assuming 8-byte `double`s). Did you check the return value of your `malloc`?

Comment: This question is marked C++, why are you using `malloc` rather than `std::vector`?  Moreover, given that you're using `malloc`, where's the call to `free`?  Also: Why are you using C-style casts?

Comment: @T.C., thank you for your reminder, I change the memory allocation part to be 'double *s1 = (double*)mkl_malloc(sizeof(double)*nn1*nn1, 64)', and compile with the ilp interface, now the code works. Do you mind answering the question and I'll accept it right away.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy, thank you for your comment, here I use CBLAS as a interface to call BLAS function which is written in fortran. CBLAS is a C interface, so I use malloc(), I have free() at the end of the function.

Comment: I use bpeek to see the real time output from the server, sometime the output is very long, what command do I need to use to redirect the output to a file on the server, so I can check? Thank you!

Comment: @user3689129 You can still use `std::vector`, which will make your code more terse, more readable, more maintainable, and safer.  `std::vector` provides the [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) method, which retrieves a pointer to the beginning of the contiguous memory it stores internally.  This can be passed to C APIs.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy,that's a good point, I'll try it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below discussion assumes:

- `sizeof(double) == 8`
- `MKL_INT` is `int`, and `sizeof(int) == 4`
- `sizeof(std::size_t) == 8`
- `CHAR_BIT == 8`

These should be true in a typical 64-bit system.

Something very interesting happens in this line:

```
s1 = (double *)malloc(q*q*sizeof(double));
```

If `q` is `50000`, then `q*q` is `2500000000`. If `q` is `int`, then this causes signed integer overflow, which causes undefined behavior. In this particular case, the compiler is likely to simply wrap around (effectively subtracting 2<sup>32</sup>), resulting in `-1794967296`.

However, when you then multiply `-1794967296` with `sizeof(double)`, which is of type `std::size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type, fun things happen. If `size_t` is 64-bit, then the compiler needs to convert `-1794967296` to an unsigned 64-bit number, and this conversion conceptually happens by adding 2<sup>64</sup> to the number, giving you `18446744071914584320`. When you multiply this by `sizeof(double)`, it overflows again, but unsigned overflow is well-defined, and returns the result modulo 2<sup>64</sup> for 64-bit operands, so the final result is `18446744059349813248`. (See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a454140c6805d7d) here for the calculations).

Thus, your original code ends up trying to allocate `18446744059349813248` bytes of memory (this is almost 16 *exabytes*). Ouch. Obviously the allocation will fail and return a null pointer. Since you didn't check the return value, you'll get a segmentation fault later.

When you rewrite this as

```
s1 = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * q * q);
```

then `sizeof(double) * q` is evaluated first. This multiplication will convert `q` to `std::size_t`, but since `q` is positive, the conversion doesn't affect its value. Thus the result is well-defined, and is a `std::size_t` with the value `400000`. The second multiplication is similarly well-defined - `q` is again converted to `std::size_t`, and the resulting multiplication produces `20000000000`, which doesn't overflow a `std::size_t`, so your `malloc` call actually requests 20GB of memory.